# C++ pointer to pointer scope issue

Tags: c++, pointers

I have a list where I store a pointer to a pointer of objects. I have a function where I create pointers to these objects and store their addresses in the list (hence pointer to a pointer). However once this function is done that pointer is no longer valid (the object is but not the pointer because it's out of scope) so now my pointer to pointer doesn't work. How do you get around this?

```
list<Actor**> lst;
void CreateEnemy()
{
    Actor* a = new Actor();

    lst.push_back(&a);
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    CreateEnemy();
    // at this point the pointer to a pointer stored in lst isn't valid anymore because it went out of scope after CreateEnemy() completed.
}
```

Comment: Is there a particular reason to store a pointer to a pointer to the object in the list instead of a pointer to the object directly?

Comment: If you *need* (please make sure you do) the pointers to pointers, I'd think you'd have to allocate an `Actor **` in your function, not just an `Actor *`.

Comment: chris how would that look? I can't get the syntax right. So Actors get created in one class and stored in this list. They get passed to Projectiles class as the projectiles target. But 5 projectiles could have the same target. The first projectile to hit the target will kill the Actor causing it to get deleted (which I want), but the other 4 projectiles will still have pointers to the now deleted target and a NULL check won't work unless I'm checking the pointer to the pointer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a simple example of something you could do based on your comments.

```
list<unique_ptr<Actor>> lst;

void CreateEnemy()
{
    lst.push_back(unique_ptr<Actor>(new Actor));
}

void KillRandomEnemies()
{
    for (auto& i : lst)
    {
        if (rand() % 100)
            i.reset();
    }
}    

class Projectile
{
public:
    Projectile(unique_ptr<Actor> & a)
        :actor(&a)
    {}

    bool IsTargetDead() const { return !(*actor); }

private:
    unique_ptr<Actor> * actor;
};

int main()
{
    CreateEnemy();
    Projectile proj(lst.front());

    while (something())
    {
        KillRandomEnemies();

        if (proj.IsTargetDead())
            whatever();
    }
}
```

Comment: what do I need with the for loop inside KillRandomEnemies()? It doesn't like that syntax and I've never seen it before. Guessing it's the new C++ style? I'm still in oldville with C++.

Comment: @user441521: Yes, it's a range-based for loop, new in C++11.  If your compiler doesn't support it, just replace it with a for loop that iterates over every element in the container.  It's been supported in GCC for a while now.  Visual C++ 10 doesn't support it, but I think version 11 does.

Answer (score 1):

Just use `std::list<Actor*>` and store the pointer. Or, even better, `std::list<Actor>`. There's nothing here that suggests a need for any pointers, much less a pointer to a pointer.

Comment: If he does need a pointer (perhaps for polymorphism), it should be a smart pointer.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley - not necessarily. A smart pointer is only appropriate when ownership is shared.

Comment: No, a smart pointer is appropriate with *any* kind of ownership.  `shared_ptr` for shared ownership, and `unique_ptr` for non-shared ownership. A non-smart pointer is only appropriate as a non-owning reference.  That's not likely the case here, since he's allocating the object dynamically.

Comment: There is polymorphism, and like Pete says I don't want to really share this. When the actor is dead I want it deleted, but many other classes may have references to it. I want to be able to check against NULL in those classes against the references but I for sure want that actor deleted when it's dead.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley - well, there are different perspectives there. A smart pointer means not having to destroy the managed objects in the manager's destructor, but it also implies sharing.

Comment: How could `unique_ptr` possibly imply sharing?  It strictly forbids it (at least in name).

Comment: I don't think either of those 2 work in this case. I could have 5 projectile objects all pointing to the same actor object as their target. When the first projectile hits the actor it sets the actor flag to dead. Later we loop through the list of actors in another class and delete and remove from list the dead actors. However the 4 other projectile classes could still be trying to move to that now deleted actor. But passing a pointer only to these projectile classes won't show that the actor was indeed deleted. Instead they point to the old area the object was in memory.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley - oh, you want to use `unique_ptr`, thus making a host of design decision that aren't present in the original question.

Comment: A unique_ptr sounds like it can only be passed around. I want all 5 of my projectiles to point to the same actor always. When I delete the actor I want it gone, but I want each projectile to know about it.

Comment: @user441521: You can store `unique_ptr`s, and in your projectiles, you can store pointers to `unique_ptr`s.

Comment: How is that any different than storing a pointer to a pointer? A pointer to a unique_ptr. A unique_ptr will go out of scope just like a normal pointer once the function is complete wont it?

Comment: @user441521: When you want to destroy the object, you reset the `unique_ptr`, so it no longer holds an object.  The pointers to the `unique_ptr` will not be dangling, and they will be able to check if the `unique_ptr` contains an object.  Your list doesn't hold pointers to `unique_ptr`s, it just holds `unique_ptr`s.  Your projectiles hold the pointers to the `unique_ptr`s.

Comment: @user441521 - exactly right: a dangling pointer is a dangling pointer. But since you've added object sharing to the requirements, look at `std::shared_ptr`. When an `Actor` is killed, mark it dead but don't destroy it. The `shared_ptr` will take care of destroying it when it's no longer needed.

Comment: but since all 5 projectiles will have a ref to the pointer when I delete the actor it won't actually delete because of the shared_ptr correct? That's not what I want. When the actor is dead it needs to be deleted I don't care if there are 4 more bullets moving towards it still. I want them to check if their target actor is NULL or not and do something accordingly.

Comment: @user441521 - why? That means that each projectile not only has to know about `Actor`s, but it has to know about how storage for `Actor`s is managed. That's generally called "coupling", and too much coupling makes code hard to maintain. If you **really** want to do that, then @BenjaminLindley's suggestion of pointers to `unique_ptr` objects works. But it seems like a bad design. Encapsulate! If an `Actor` is dead, mark it dead.

Comment: A projectile needs to know where it's target is and if it's target is a moving actor it needs to know about the actor. How else do you tell the projectile about it's target without having it know about the actor? Also I do mark it dead from within the actor. The projectile just needs to know the current location of the actor and so it gets a pointer to it so it can query it (because it moves).

Answer (score 0):

Try this :
after the call to createEnemy :

```
Actor * a = * lst.front();
a -> some function.
```

Is this still doing problems?

I tested the code on my own class and it was fine.